# Create new columns based on matching ID

Tags: pandas

I've got the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 10, 25, 25],
    'Col 1': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y'],
    'Col 2': ['Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X'],
    'Val 1': [100, 20, 350, 500, 3],
    'Val 2': [20, 100, 9, 16, 500]
}).set_index('ID')
```

and I want to create columns on matched ID, taking into account both Col 1 and Val 1 (notice when ID match, the values of Col 1 and Col 2 are swapped), i.e. I want to create the following:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 10, 25, 25],
    'Col 1': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y'],
    'Col 2': ['Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X'],
    'Val 1': [100, 20, 350, 500, 3],
    'Val 1 Wanted': [100, 20, 350, 500, 16],
    'Val 2': [20, 100, 9, 16, 500],
    'Val 2 Wanted': [20, 100, 9, 3, 500],
}).set_index('ID')
```

Comment: Will there be only two rows per group? If there are more how do you want to swap them?

Comment: @XXavier Yes, only two rows per group.